# realm export objects to JSON

Tags: realm

Are realm database files platform independent ? For example, if I copy a realm database file from an iOS device to an Android device, will it work ? I am not able to find this from the docs. I cannot use realm platform for file synchronisation though.

Also, in case the file is not cross-platform, if I want to export the data and import it into JSON, what will be the code for the export ? I can find the import code as mentioned in https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json But I cannot find any way to export the contents of a realm database to JSON (Kotlin/Java and Swift are the languages that I care, if it matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got an answer from the realm forums. The .realm file can be moved across platforms and it is expected to work. Also, there is no native way to export a realm database to JSON as of now (January 2018) as JSON cannot handle cycles, while realm can.

Forum discussion url: https://forums.realm.io/t/realm-export-import-and-cross-platform-nature-of-the-realm-file/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in title - now there is a tool [realm2json](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/blob/master/src/realm/exec/realm2json.cpp) in [realm-core](https://github.com/realm/realm-core) to export realm as json. It can be built by specifying `Realm2JSON` as build target (`cmake --build . --target Realm2JSON`).